# How to update ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

### How do you update ng-model from view in this case?

I am having a problem updating my ng-model. Sorry if this with errors or I am doing something wrong! I am pretty new to web development!

My HTML code looks something like this:

```
<div id="loadedCart" ng-show="ifLoadCart">
        <div ng-repeat="book in cartbooks" repeat-finish>
            <br>
            <!--<img src="book.path" alt="img of book"></img>-->
            <h6 ng-click="deleteBook(book.id)">{{book.name}}</h6>
            <h6>{{book.authors}}</h6>
            <h6>{{book.price}}</h6>
            <h6>{{book.qboy}}</h6>
            <input ng-model="thisoneshould" type="number" min="0" required>
            <input type="submit" ng-click="changeQuant(book.id)" value="Update quantity">
            <br><br><br>
        </div>
        <div><button ng-click="checkout()">Checkout</button></div>
    </div>
```

And my code in the controller looks something like this:

```
    $scope.thisoneshould = 0;
    //other variables that are defined...

    $scope.changeQuant = function(x){
        $scope.updateCart(x);
    }
    $scope.updateCart = function(x){
        $scope.showLoginErrorMsg = false;
        $scope.needToLogin = false;
        $scope.showLoginErrorMsg = false;
        $scope.ifhomepage = false;
        $scope.ifSuccessful = false;
        $scope.ifbookpage = false;
        $scope.ifcheckpage = false;
        $scope.ifShowQuantity = false;
        $scope.additionSuccess = false;
        $scope.ifLoadCart = true;
        console.log(x);
        console.log($scope.thisoneshould);
        //$scope.cartbooks = [];
        if ($scope.thisoneshould!=0)
        {
            console.log($scope.thisoneshould);
            $http.put('updatecart',{'bookId': x, 'quantity': $scope.thisoneshould}).then(function(response){
                $scope.itemsInCart = response.data;
           });
        }
        else {
            $http.delete('deletefromcart/'+x).then(function(response){
                $scope.itemsInCart = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what seems to be the problem with my code, why it is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by not updating? you are not updating anywhere

Comment: Oh! I am sorry I just started angular day before. How do you update the model in my case? @Sajeetharan Because I thought just giving input ng-model would do.

Comment: just set the value $scope.thisoneshould to the new value

Comment: you want `ng-model` assigned to some property of `book` probably .... `ng-model="book.someProperty"`

Comment: But I want to detect what was written in the input box and then give $scope.thisoneshould that value

Comment: @Sajeetharan any advice on that?

Comment: Follow the rule of always have a dot in your ng-models. See [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to notify the controller whenever the value is changed. Some sort of event to update the value in controller.

Angularjs is anyways offers the feature of two way data binding. your variable should have the updated value. In the below example i am using **`ng-change`** with **`ng-model`**

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here

var app =angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.updated = 0;
   $scope.print = function(test){
     console.log(test);
   }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
     <input ng-model="thisoneshould" ng-change="print(thisoneshould)" type="number" min="0" required>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I also wanted to clarify if I do this, since ng-repeat has the same variable for different input boxes, will it affect any thing? As the other values will not change?

Comment: if you have the same variable indeed it will have an effect. otherwise no need to worry

Comment: Ok the value of thisoneshould is changing when I console.log it. But when I use it in some other function, it says undefined. Any insights on it!

Comment: you have to pass to the function when you are calling $scope.2ndfunc($scope.thisoneshould) and use it inside 2nd function

Comment: btw  as @georgeawg mentioned above you should always use ng-model over an object